# Cannot mount openSuSE NTFS partitions that were automatically created

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, ntfs, opensuse

I am using openSuSE and Windows 7 together.

#### Partitions

```
Device    Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    53944319    26971136    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2        53946272    60034904     3044316+  83  Linux
/dev/sda3   *    60035072   201345023    70654976    5  Extended
/dev/sda4       201345024   625141759   211898368    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda5       187015168   201345023     7164928   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6        60037120   101980159    20971520   83  Linux
/dev/sda7       101982208   187013119    42515456   83  Linux
```

sda3 is an extended 60 GB partition. When I installed OpenSuSE it automatically created two partitions from sda3 (sda6 for root and sda7 for home).

Now I can't mount NTFS partitions. How can I mount them?

I tried `mount` command and now checked ntfs-3g but it warns me that:

> Mount is denied because the NTFS volume is already exclusively opened.